# Prestashop webservice key lost

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i have setup a local webserver and a fresh prestashop 1.6.1 installation.
I have added a webservice key and activate the service.
I have write a script and all works!
But after a lot of time (minutes) the key disappear and the service is shutted down!
I have searched a lot of time in the documentations regardling an expire time for the keys or webservice but i havn't found nothing!
Anyone can help me?
Thanks and sorry for the english!!

Comment: did you enable multistore mode during these operations?

Comment: Solved! The problem was generated by misconfiguration of webserver!